# Containerised Nifi s2s Issue

Tags: docker, https, apache-nifi

I am using this :- https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi/;
running the below for secure instance :-

```
docker run --name nifi \
  -v /User/hddev/certs/localhost:/opt/certs \
  -p 8443:8443 \
  -e AUTH=tls \
  -e NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST=ec2-hostname.aws.com:8443 \
  -e KEYSTORE_PATH=/opt/certs/keystore.jks \
  -e KEYSTORE_TYPE=JKS \
  -e KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=securepass \
  -e TRUSTSTORE_PATH=/opt/certs/truststore.jks \
  -e TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=securepass \
  -e TRUSTSTORE_TYPE=JKS \
  -e INITIAL_ADMIN_IDENTITY='CN=admin, OU=NIFI' \
  -d \
  apache/nifi:latest
```

WebUI works fine I am able to access but with *s2s* I get this at the RPG,

> java.net.UnknownHostException for docker-container-id:8443
>   o.a.n.r.util.SiteToSiteRestApiClient Failed to create transaction for
>   https://docker-container-id:8443/nifi-api/data-transfer/input-ports/someportaddress/transactions

When I see the property for ,it takes the container id :- 2eftfdf
nifi.web.https.host=2eftfdf
nifi.remote.input.host=2eftfdf
due to below code.

https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-docker/dockerhub/sh/secure.sh#L61

I was able to get it work by by changing the environment variable $HOSTNAME to public dns of ec2.
Is there setting in to achieve this without chaging. env

Do we need to update nifi.remote.route.{protocol}.{name}.when related properties? If not then how?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not setting `NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_HOST` through the Docker environment variables command? That property is used for the external-facing hostname, which is what you want in this case.

Comment: I did try to set NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_HOST but it gets overriden by https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-docker/dockerhub/sh/secure.sh#L61

Comment: @Andy   is there any other way or config to achieve this?

Comment: The line you linked to should populate the value of the environment variable `NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_HOST` if present, or `HOSTNAME` if not. What values are you providing and what is the result in the properties file?